# How to enable cookies in ffmpeg HLS

Tags: cookies, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Anyone know how to enable cookie interaction in ffmpeg? I have an HLS stream who need save cookies from the server , but actually that doesn't happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no cookie support in ffmpeg. You'll need to implement that part on your own or perhaps use mplayer which supports cookies.

Answer (score 18):

You can send
[headers with](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/ff-cookie.sh)
FFmpeg

Linux

```sh
ffmpeg -i INPUT -headers $'Cookie: logged_in=yes; tracker=direct\r\n'
```

Windows

```sh
powershell ffmpeg -i INPUT -headers "Cookie: logged_in=yes; tracker=direct`r`n"
```

Comment: ok, I was reading about that but I want the posibility to save cookies between playlist calls. Actually my server need the cookies saved to calculate the next playlist m3u8

Comment: The provided link leads to a 404.

Comment: @Akito, I found similar script https://github.com/als888/a/blob/master/scripts/ff-cookie.sh but you have to replace `ffplay` with `ffmpeg`