# FFmpeg code not working on http url for thumbnail extraction

Tags: sharepoint, video, ffmpeg, image-extraction

I am trying to extract thumbnail from sharepoint 2013 video library. I found a link which can extract using ffmpeg. this is the link:
[[How can I save first frame of a video as image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575311/how-can-i-save-first-frame-of-a-video-as-image][1])

```
filename = "http://siteurl/" + items["FileRef"].ToString();
```

When i replaced the input file with sharepoint site url and video name then it does not produce any thumbnail. I also gives error on

```
ffmpeg.Start();
        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
        ffmpeg.Close()
```

I would like to understand how make it work for http url. 
If it is not possible to use url in ffmpeg can anyone suggest another method to achieve thumbnail.(as i want the thumbnail to be set automatically using 1st frame from of video if it not set manually)

Answer (score 1):

I tested below parameters they worked. to extract first frame from remote video.

```
ffmpeg -i "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" -f image2 -vframes 1 "e:\images\01\image%03d.jpg"
```

to extract image from specific duration of the video (first frame maybe black) use the **-ss** parameter. **-ss 00:00:02** means take image at 2th second. (more specific frame **-ss 00:00:02.xxx** xxx=0 to 999 milliseconds)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:02 -i "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" -f image2 -vframes 1 "e:\images\01\image%03d.jpg"
```

update the code [How can I save first frame of a video as image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575311/how-can-i-save-first-frame-of-a-video-as-image) as your need.

**Updates**

Below commands failed with **Invalid data found when processing input** but you can find a solution to your question by trying **-cookies** or **-headers** parameters.
When authentication is required **-cookies** or **-headers** arguments can be used as below. When you log in to server use **[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)** to get cookies and add them to ffmpeg **-cookies** or **-headers** parameters.

```
ffmpeg -cookies "path=/; domain=domainname.com; cookiesgoeshere\r\n" -i "video url goes here" -f image2 -vframes 1 "e:\image%03d.jpg"
```

or

```
ffmpeg -headers "Cookie: path=/; domain=domainname.com; cookiesgoeshere\r\n" -i "video url goes here" -f image2 -vframes 1 "e:\image%03d.jpg"
```

related topics

[How to enable cookies in ffmpeg HLS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105929/how-to-enable-cookies-in-ffmpeg-hls)

or [Zeranoe FFmpeg - View topic - Custom http headers](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1415)

another option is **run ffmpeg in your web server**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I got the http running but only for anonymous sharepoint site access. If i use it with sharepoint site which needs sign in it doesn't produce the thumbnail. This is what I am doing.static string filename = "http://abc24:23478/FirstVideo%20list/Wildlife.wmv";

ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + filename + " -an -ss 00:00:01 " + output;ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Zeba\VideoThumbnail\ffmpeg.exe";