# set useragent in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

How to set useragent in ffmpeg ?.

I implemented SWF verification in Media server and allowed some user agents for not to check SWF. But Problem is, I'm unable to set useragent in FFMPEG. As I need to repubish one of my stream with low bit rate to core server using ffmpeg.

```
FFMPEG Version : ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1

SWF verification enabled in 172.20.1.10 server
```

Tried formats :

```
ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.11.12.13/live/mystreams -c copy -f flv  "rtmp://172.20.1.10/live/testnew -headers "UserAgent: 'FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)'"

ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.11.12.13/live/mystreams -c copy -f flv  "rtmp://172.20.1.10/live/testnew -user_agent 'FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)'"

ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.11.12.13/live/mystreams -c copy -f flv  "rtmp://172.20.1.10/live/testnew -user-agent 'FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)'"
```

Answer (score 13):

First thing first, the OP attempts has broken quotes:

```
"... "rtmp://172.20.1.10/live/testnew -user_agent 'FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)'"
```

The `-user-agent` option is deprecated, it will shows warning:

```
$ ffmpeg  -user-agent "using -user-agent UA"  -i 'https://example.com' -v trace |& grep -i user-agent 
Reading option '-user-agent' ... matched as AVOption 'user-agent' with argument 'using -user_agent UA'.
[https @ 0x55df7b9dc320] the user-agent option is deprecated, please use user_agent option
User-Agent: using -user-agent UA
```

You need `-user_agent` (i.e. underscore `_`, not dash `-`):

```
$ ffmpeg  -user_agent "using -user_agent UA"  -i 'https://example.com' -v trace |& grep -i user-agent 
User-Agent: using -user_agent UA
```

If you added `-headers 'User-Agent: '`, it will override `-user_agent`:

```
$ ffmpeg -user_agent "using -user_agent UA" -headers 'User-Agent: using -headers UA'  -i 'https://example.com' -v trace |& grep -i user-agent 
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: using -headers UA'.
User-Agent: using -headers UA
```

But if your syntax is wrong when trying to add multiple headers, then `-headers` will not able to override and still using default `Lavf/` or `-user_agent`:

```
$ ffmpeg  -user_agent "using -user_agent UA" -headers 'User-Agent: using -headers UA' -headers 'Accept: */*' -i 'https://example.com' -v trace |& grep -i user-agent 
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: using -headers UA'.
User-Agent: using -user_agent UA
```

Only if you using correct syntax on multiple headers (i.e. single `-headers` + `\r\n`), then `-headers 'User-Agent:`  will able to override default `Lavf/` or `-user_agent`:

```
$ ffmpeg  -user_agent "using -user_agent UA" -headers 'User-Agent: using -headers UA'$'\r\n''Accept: */*' -i 'https://example.com' -v trace |& grep -i user-agent 
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: using -headers UA
User-Agent: using -headers UA
```

Comment: Adding `-headers "User-Agent: My User Agent"` **after** the `-i` param will not change the user agent. To be sure, add the  `-headers` parameter **as the first argument**!

Answer (score 6):

```
ffmpeg -user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3554.0 Safari/537.36" -headers "origin: https://glive.gaodun.com" -headers "referer: https://glive.gaodun.com/space.html?isV"  -i https://vod.gaodun.com/13p9Wv580v1a!!fs/SD/1.m3u8 -c copy demo.mp4
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
-headers 'User-Agent: "FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)"'
```

[User agent - Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Also, you might need to include CRLF:

```sh
-headers $'User-Agent: "FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)"\r\n'
```

[How to enable cookies in ffmpeg HLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16105929/#16109670)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
-user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Companybot/1.0; +http://www.Thecompany.com)"
```